# How to print filename and function name using spdlog?

Tags: c++, fmt, spdlog

Following [spdlog documentation](https://spdlog.docsforge.com/v1.x/3.custom-formatting/#customizing-format-using-set_pattern) I was able to modify the print pattern

```
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"
#include "spdlog/sinks/daily_file_sink.h"

int main()
{
    spdlog::set_pattern("%H:%M:%S.%e %t %s %! %v");

    auto logger = spdlog::daily_logger_mt("daily_logger", "../../../logs/daily.txt", 2, 30);

    logger->info("casdc");

    return 0;
}
```

With the above I see `daily_logger.txt` contents below:

```
01:41:35.895 70101   casdc
01:44:22.719 71978   casdc
01:44:35.225 72232   casdc
```

But I was expecting to see also:

> ```
> %s Basename of the source file  
> %! Source function
> ```

Why I'm not seeing those?

Actually it seems to work if I call

```
 SPDLOG_LOGGER_INFO(logger, "{:>10}", "vsvfsdfv");
```

But then my question is when should I call

```
logger->info("casdc");
```

Comment: You can't for now. There is a tracking issue [#1823](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/issues/1823) for this feature, using C++20 `std::source_location`.

Answer (score 1):

`SPDLOG_LOGGER_INFO(logger, "{:>10}", "vsvfsdfv")` it works, but it doesn't work when `SPDLOG_LOGGER_TRACE(logger, "message")`,the log level is invalid